# Selected radio button for filter doesn't visually retain state when toggling between 'Show all rows' and 'Group' modes

Tags: javascript

[THIS](https://pastebin.com/raw/f9tvMwRB) is the complete code 
 I share it because the type of problem I expose here is integrated into a slightly complex dynamic

This is the problem using a picture

[image: radiobutton]

When a radio button is selected, the following function is executed which updates the selectedBadge variable with the value of the selected radio button:

```
$('input[name="badgeFilter"]').change(function() {
    selectedBadge = $(this).val();
    var filteredData = selectedBadge ? data.filter(item => item.badge === selectedBadge) : data;
    initializeDataTable(filteredData);
});
```

When switching from "Mostra tutte le righe" mode to "Raggruppa" mode, the following function is performed which saves the value of the radio button selected before the switch:

```
$('#raggruppaButton').click(function() {
    var selectedRadioValueBefore = $('input[name="badgeFilter"]:checked').val();
    grouped = !grouped;
    // ...
    // Resets the value of the selected radio button
    $('input[name="badgeFilter"][value="'+selectedRadioValueBefore+'"]').prop('checked', true);
});
```

These parts of the code are responsible for managing the radio button and maintaining its state

When you switch from "Raggruppa" mode to "Mostra tutte le righe", the code responsible for this action is located in the function associated with the button's click event `#raggruppaButton`. This function changes the state of the grouped variable and updates the table accordingly.

Here is the code for this transition:

```
$('#raggruppaButton').click(function() {
    var selectedRadioValueBefore = $('input[name="badgeFilter"]:checked').val();
    grouped = !grouped;

    searchValue = dataTable.search(); // Save the current search value
    toggleButtonLabel(); // Update the button label

    fetchDataAndInitializeTable(); // Reload and initialize the table with the new data

    if (grouped) {
        $('#userTable').addClass('grouped-mode'); // Adds CSS class for grouped mode
    } else {
        $('#userTable').removeClass('grouped-mode'); // Removes the CSS class for grouped mode
    }

    // Resets the value of the selected radio button
    $('input[name="badgeFilter"][value="'+selectedRadioValueBefore+'"]').prop('checked', true);
});
```

In this function, the following operations are performed:

- The value of the radio button selected before the step is saved.
- The state of the grouped variable is reversed.
- The current search value is saved.
- The `toggleButtonLabel` function is called to update the button label.
- The `fetchDataAndInitializeTable` function is called to reload and initialize the table with the new data.
- If the mode is grouped, a grouped-mode CSS class is added to the table to apply the correct styling.
- If the mode is not grouped, the grouped-mode CSS class is removed.
- Finally, the value of the selected radio button is restored using the `selectedRadioValueBefore`.